# Castle Windsor compile time error

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, castle-windsor

So I downloaded and extracted the latest version of the Windsor IoC container today (2.5.2) and for some reason that is beyond me, keeps spitting out this horribly basic error when I try to compile:

*The type or namespace name 'Castle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Thing is - I HAVE referenced both the Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor assemblies (and various other combinations thereof) and still no luck. I'm guessing I *must* be doing something stupid but can't figure out what. This is for .NET 4.0.

Any ideas? Anyone? All constructive help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using VS2010? If so, try to go project properties -> Application Tab and make sure that you are not using a Framework version that has "client profile" in it.

Comment: BTW there *is* a specific build included in the package targeting .NET 4 client profile.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, can you please tell me where I can find the one for client profile? thanks